# PCA method for feature selection - How to solve the raise Exception error ("Data must be 1-dimensional")?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Função que permitirá rankear as features mais importantes em um barhplot
def ranks_PCA (x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH='Results'):
    print("\nMétodo PCA")

    pca = PCA(n_components=58)
    pca.fit_transform(x_train)

    imp_array = np.array(pca.components_)
    imp_order = imp_array.argsort()
    ranks = imp_order.argsort()

    # Plot PCA
    imp = pd.Series(pca.components_, index=x_train.columns)
    imp = imp.sort_values()

    imp.plot(kind="barh")
    plt.xlabel("Importance")
    plt.ylabel("Features")
    plt.title("Feature importance using PCA")
    # plt.show()
    plt.savefig(RESULT_PATH + '/ranks_DT.png', bbox_inches='tight')

    return ranks
```

---

```
#Função para predição das features dos dados de teste
def predict_PCA(x_test_sel, k_vetor, y_train):
    model = decomposition.PCA()
    model.fit(k_vetor, y_train)
    y_predict = model.predict(x_test_sel)
    return(y_predict)
```

---

```
#Função que calcula o ranking dos dados de treinamento
ranks4 = frk.ranks_PCA(x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH)
```

I have doubts if this implementation is correct to obtain more important features. When trying to run this code, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "feat_test.py", line 235, in
>   'Results/PDBbind2018_F58_Delta_pKd') File "feat_test.py", line 78, in
>   run_experiment ranks4 = frk.ranks_PCA(x_train, y_train,
>   features_train, RESULT_PATH) File "C:\Users\Patricia\Desktop\VT-58 -
>   Cópia\feature-importance\feature_rank_
>   ensemble\Scripts\feature_ranks.py", line 121, in ranks_PCA imp =
>   pd.Series(pca.components_, index=x_train.columns) File
>   "C:\Users\Patricia\Desktop\VT-58 -
>   Cópia\feature-importance\feature_rank_
>   ensemble\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 305, in
>   init data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy,
>   raise_cast_failure=True) File "C:\Users\Patricia\Desktop\VT-58 -
>   Cópia\feature-importance\feature_rank_
>   ensemble\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 482,
>   in saniti ze_array raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")

Can anybody help me?

Comment: it's not possible to correlate your error traceback with your code, so it's difficult to understand where the error comes from. you'll get more useful answers if you can create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pca.components_` is a 2d array, so you cannot make a Series out of it.

Comment: simple answer but it really helped me to find the error, thank you very much.